# Download file and rename according to file type using python urllib

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have this code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.downloadcrew.com/article/28976-flicflac"
pageurl = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageurl)
app_name = soup.find('div',{'id':'articleTop'}).find('h1',{'id':'articleTitle'}).contents[0].strip()
download_link = "http://www.downloadcrew.com"+soup.find('div',{'class':'downloadLink'}).find('a')['href'].split(',')[1].strip().strip("'")
source = urllib.urlopen(download_link).read()
print "Downloading: "+(app_name)
filename = (app_name)
files = open(filename,'w')
files.write(source)
files.close()
```

When I run this code, the downloaded file should be name 'flicflac.zip'
But what I get is not 'flicflac.zip'. It is a file extension.
How to make it automatically name as above?

Comment: What is the output of the `print` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the file Content Type, and add extension accordingly:

```
from mimetypes import guess_extension

source = urllib.urlopen(download_link)
extension = guess_extension(source.info()['Content-Type'])
if extension:
    app_name += extension
else:
    # what to do? discard?
    pass

# later do source.read()
```

Comment: How to name it automatically without have to name it manually?

Comment: I am confuse. for the source.read(),why the archive is corrupted?

Comment: Change write mode from `w` to `wb+`